# Distributing "Free" Android App as .apk file directly

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have already published android app on Google Play. It is desired to distribute the application even offline as  .apk file directly. My app is completely free and we wish it should spread to as many people.

I am not sure what could be advantages and disadvantages of providing .apk file?

Questions are :

1. Will Google play count direct .apk installation as a download, when connected to internet ?
2. Will users with direct .apk installation get any update published later ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Google play collects statistics of Apps **only installed through Play Store** , with a Google account logged in. [Read Documentation on App statistics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628).
2. Newer version of Play Store app can auto detect **if** any of installed app is also available on play store, and will notify for the update.

Also, there are numerous third party app markets other than Play Store. You can upload your app there too (auto update is not available with all of them).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, you will get a download prompt if you click on an `.apk` in Android. When you go to open the completed download, it will offer it up for install (see caveats below)
2. If you offer your `.apk` up for direct download outside of Google Play you get no "update checking" -- you have to do that yourself. Not entirely sure what happens if the `.apk` is available in the play store and via direct download.

---

It is easier to talk about the disadvantages for the approach of distributing the `.apk` yourself.

1. You have to do all the tracking yourself, if you publish to the play store you get some statistics
2. Similarly, you have to do all "update checking" on your own (either via writing it in your app or some other way.)
3. No secure way of distributing your application. The built in Android browser does not support downloads over HTTPS streams that require authentication **
4. Easier for users to get the source code of your app. They can download the `.apk` from your site, open it in 7zip (or similar) and have at the underlying class files. Whether or not this is a concern is really for you to decide.

**The most important reason**

Your users will have to check "Allow installation of packages from unknown sources". Your average person might not know how to do this, and may be hesitant to do so. So, it may limit your ability to gain a a wide market share.

So, in summary, ask yourself if *not* being in  Google Play/Android Market is  really worth the hassle that comes for both you and your users.

** Not sure if this is true with Chrome on Android -- it is certainly true with the older default browser

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems no, correct me if I am wrong :)
2. Yes, provided that the package name is the same and the version code of the apk file you've uploaded to google play is larger than the one installed in the device.